# How to Represent DFS BFS Graphs and Trees using Graphics in C++

Tags: c++, graphics

So I want to implement Breadth first Search and Depth First Search in C++ and then also want to show it Graphically. 
Like initially I want to show the graph entered by the User (stored in Adjacency matrix) and then After Traversing via Bfs Or Dfs I want to show one by one the node Processed.

The DFS BFS Codes are Ready but now i want to extend it to graphical representation. 
I want that as the first vertice is processed, A circle inside which vertexName is printed is added on the screen then the next Vertex processed is added and joined to the previous vertex which is already there on the screen and so on the process continues.

Kindly Guide me to make such kind of Graphical Representation in C++

Comment: GraphViz can do this sort of thing for you; you can either use its calculations to generate your own graphics, or you can have your program output an ASCII representation of the graph you want to display, and then pass that ASCII representation into the "dot" utility and it will output a bitmap file containing the graph.

Comment: Thanks for the directions, I'll checki that out.